# Button next to input

Tags: html, css

I need to place a fixed-width `button` next to an full-width `input`, so together they'll be full-width. How do I do this?

```
<div>
  <input placeholder="example">
  <button>></button>
</div>

<style>
    div {height: 30px}
    div > * {height: 100%}

    input {width: 100%}
    button {width: 30px}
</style>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14Lxg860/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Flexbox** can do that.

```css
    div {
      height: 30px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 5em auto;
      border:1px solid grey;
    }

    input {
      -webkit-box-flex:1;
      -webkit-flex:1;
          -ms-flex:1;
              flex:1;
    }
    
    button {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -webkit-flex: 0 0 30px;
          -ms-flex: 0 0 30px;
              flex: 0 0 30px
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <input placeholder="example">
  <button>></button>
</div>
```

**Absolute Positioning**

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top:5em;
  padding-right: 30px;
  /* width of button */
}
div > * {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input {
  width: 100%
}
button {
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input placeholder="example">
  <button>></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

While Paulie_D's `flexbox` solution is the recommended way of doing it, if you need your code to work on iPhone lower than 5S you can use this `block-model` legacy solution:

```css
 div {
   height: 30px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 div > * {
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0;
 }
 input {
   width: calc(100% - 30px);
 }
 button {
   width: 30px;
   float: right;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <input placeholder="example">
  <button>></button>
</div>
```

Please note that the selectors used in this example are **way too broad** to be used in a production environment. You need to make them more specific, so they don't affect unwanted elements.