# How to inline a button/dropdown with an input text box?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

[image: Inline button next to input]

How would something like this be achieved, having a perfect button next to the input like that?

Comment: Use browser code inspector and you might find your answer.

Comment: add your code and people can help out

Comment: I just want to get a button next to a text input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button next to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707738/button-next-to-input)

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51068845/edit) your question and add the code you have already tried, then people will help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution for you. The `position: absolute` causes the space between button and input to be removed, and make it "inline" with the input. I used `border-left: none` to remove the extra border where it lines up with the input. This can even be done with flex as well!

```css
button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #4080ff;
  color: white;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>></button>
```