# positioning a button inside the input field

Tags: html, css

I want to place a button inside my input exactly like this:

[image]

So far I have the input but I'm unable to find a solution to place the button properly.

```css
.realoutercontainer {
  padding: 10% 0;
  position:relative;  
}

.outercontainer {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(207,215,223,.25);
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 30px 40px 10px 40px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 60px -12px rgba(50,50,93,.25),0 18px 36px -18px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  box-shadow: 0 30px 60px -12px rgba(50,50,93,.25),0 18px 36px -18px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #6c6770;
  font-family: "Vazir";
}




.realoutercontainer.settings{
  padding: 2% 0; 
}

.settings .outercontainer {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 94%;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}





.settings-input {
  margin: 50px 0;
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.settings-input input {
  display: inline-block;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ededed;
  color: #743db0;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
  
.settings-input input:focus {
  color: #8e5bc5;
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #e7572c;
}

.settings-input .input-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column ;
}

.settings-input .uname{
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
        
        <div class="realoutercontainer settings">
            <div class="outercontainer">

              <div class="settings-input">

                <div class="input-field">
                  <div for="fname" class="uname">نام کاربری :</div>
                  <div><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="user_1252442"/></div>
                  <button type="submit">ویرایش</button>
                </div>

              </div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. First `<input>` is an empty tag, as such you can't place a button inside it technical-wise. Also you shouldn't because it would be invalid HTML markup. The only way you could achieve it is with wrapping both elements and use `position: relative/absolute` and layer them above each other. However then you need to set a margin to the input field as otherwise the input text will be hidden by the button. Overall a terrible approach -> You should not attempt to do this!

Comment: This has been asked a lot of times. Here is one specific question with button and input.  [Button next to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707738/button-next-to-input)

Comment: Hello, OP!
It would be nice if you could choose an answer that suited you the most.

Answer (score 2):

```css
div,
form,
input {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: coral;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label> نام کاربری : </label>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Some Text..." />
    <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can change the styles or whatever you want accordingly. I showed how its done.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes, follow the code, I hope it helps you.
It is not styled, it is in raw form.

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2.3em;
}

.group-wrapper {
  width: 50em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.content {
  padding-left: 7em;
  background: #EDEDED;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}

.uname {
  margin:0 9em 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
} 
button {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: start;
  color: #E1E5ED;
  background: #ED1C24;
  padding: 0.4em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="user" class="uname">نام کاربری :</label>
  <div class="group-wrapper">
    <input id="user" class="content" type="text" placeholder="user_1252442" />
    <button type="submit">ویرایش</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why is it not styled ?

Comment: @MihaiT this is something you do for your project. Every person/project have a unique design.
That's just the code to get things ready, like the OP requested.

Comment: OP, as far as i can see, posted an image on how the end result should look like. That's why i was asking why no styling

Comment: @MihaiT I've edited and used color picker to use same colors as OP requested on post.
Was a little hard for me to use that Persian Word.

Comment: You didn't need to use that exact word or the exact color. But the ' look and feel ' to be the same. You could've use ` Submit` as the text and `red` as the color :)

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly borrowing from @Kunal, this version puts the button on the left as desired:

```css
div,
form,
input {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label> نام کاربری : </label>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Some Text..." />
    <button> My button </button>
  </div>
</form>
```